# Algorithm to generating function mapping sets of integers [0,N] to [0,M] where M <= N

Tags: c++, compression

Here's the problem, I'm looking to map all the integers in the range [0, N) to integers in the range [0, M] (where M < N). Specifically to map sets of integers to integers in the range [0, M] such that no set's output may collide with another. Things we have: We have all the sets of integers as inputs, we do not necessarily know or care which set maps to which number*. This adds another potential limitation (but one we'd want) that M is the # of input sets. The purpose of the mapping is to compress the range [0, N) into as small as possible a range [0, M] as possible. For completeness, any integers not found in the input sets could be considered their own set and any numbers appearing in multiple sets should be considered their own unique set. This creates a unique mapping for every integer to [0,M] where M is the # of sets as inputs. N here would be 2^(however many bits).

I'm looking to generate a function (not a table). A table isn't so bad to accomplish, the algorithm to generate the table is somewhat given away by the restrictions, it's possible to use a bit of extra memory to eventually generate a smaller table. However I'm memory bound and the input space is 32 bit integers, meaning a table 2^32 bytes large or even ones 2^16 large are just not feasible. I'll be generating quite a few of these functions, 256 bytes per may not be so bad, 2^16 or 2^32 is far too much. I've already written an algorithm to create a table for 8 bit integers because that's a nicer case to deal with and I'm happy to have 256 bytes live on the stack. So instead I'm curious if there's an algorithm, or other bithackery that can accomplish this and not consume a ton of memory. Another consideration is these generated functions will be hot, the instructions that make up the function should probably be branchless, as the inputs [0,N) which will be fed to the generated function are for all practical purposes random.

Some trivial examples, say we have only one set which contains the numbers [0, N) then the generated function should return 0 no matter the input. If we have two sets [0, N/2), [N/2, N) then the generated function should return 0 or 1, depending which set the input was in. If we have N-1 sets with unique integers from [0, N) then we have what would be an identity function or a perfect hash function. However since we're about compression here, the last case is the worst case scenario, however ideally this is the identity function so we do absolutely no work.
Since* these are sets of integers and we don't necessarily care about the order of their input here we might note that if we order the sets by their lowest member and we map sets in order to unique numbers, this should eventually work out to the identity function. And crossing fingers the optimizer works out it doesn't have to any work we'd be all good. However, since we know the sets at start we can check for this case and use the identity function instead.

My initial thought process was that maybe it'd be possible to work out the important bit indexes for every integer, making some sort of mask, eventually working towards a mapping for every bit based on which one's appear most/least important and shuffle the input integer's bits into the least significant bits. I don't bit hack much but it strikes me to be potentially in the right direction.

Here's part of what builds a 8 bit table.

```c
//previous is the table as it stands
//equiv_class is a set of integers
//returns the new table
    template<typename Ty>
    constexpr stack_vector::stack_vector<Ty, 256> make_equivalence_class(stack_vector::stack_vector<Ty, 256> previous, stack_vector::stack_vector<uint8_t, 256> equiv_class) {
        stack_vector::stack_vector<Ty, 256> ecs{};
        ::std::array<uint16_t, 256> counts{};

        stack_vector::stack_vector<Ty, 256> current = previous;
        if (equiv_class.size()) {
            //make a mapping to collapse the equivalence classes together
            for (size_t i=0; i < current.size(); i++) {
                size_t tmp = current[i];
                auto it = std::find(ecs.begin(), ecs.end(), tmp);
                size_t ec = std::distance(ecs.begin(), it);
                if (it == ecs.end())
                    ecs.emplace_back(tmp);
                current[i] = ec;
                counts[ec]+=1;
            }
            size_t mx = 0;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < equiv_class.size(); i++) {
                mx = ((mx >= equiv_class[i]) ? mx : equiv_class[i]);
            }
            //add indexs we're missing
            size_t lim = mx + 1;
            size_t last_size = ecs.size();
                
            for (size_t i = current.size(); i < lim; i++) {
                current.emplace_back(last_size);
                counts[last_size]++;
            }
            //partition input indexs based on equivalence class
            //use ecs just for the memory
            ecs.clear();
            for (size_t i = 0; i < equiv_class.size(); i++) {
                size_t idx = equiv_class[i];
                size_t key = current[equiv_class[i]];
                size_t j = 0;
                for (; j < ecs.size(); j++) {
                    size_t key2 = current[ecs[j]];
                    if (key == key2) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                size_t j2 = j;
                size_t j3 = j;
                for (; j2 < ecs.size(); ++j2, j3=j2) {
                    size_t key2 = current[ecs[j2]];
                    if (idx == ecs[j2] || key != key2) {
                        j3 = ((idx == ecs[j2]) ? j2 : ecs.size());
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //if idx was not found (removes duplicates)
                if (j3 == ecs.size()) {
                    //make space
                    ecs.emplace_back();
                    //move backwards
                    Ty* first = (&ecs[0]) + j2;
                    Ty* last = (&ecs[0]) + (ecs.size() - 1);
                    Ty* d_last = (&ecs[0]) + (ecs.size());
                    while (first != last) {
                        *(--d_last) = std::move(*(--last));
                    }
                    //insert
                    ecs[j2] = idx;
                }
            }

            equiv_class.clear();
            for (size_t i = 0; i < ecs.size(); i++) {
                equiv_class.unchecked_emplace_back(ecs[i]);
            }

            //now we're remapping every integer to itself
            ecs.clear();
            for (size_t i = 0; i < (last_size + 1); i++)
                ecs.unchecked_emplace_back(i);

            size_t last_size_2 = ecs.size();
            //merge new indexs
            for (size_t j=0; j < equiv_class.size(); j++) {
                size_t i = equiv_class[j];
                size_t current_ec = current[i];
                size_t remapped_ec = ecs[current_ec];
                size_t current_count = counts[current_ec];
                size_t remapped_count = counts[remapped_ec];
                if (current_ec == remapped_ec) {
                    if (current_count == 1) {
                        //if there's only 1 to start w/ anyway, leave as is
                    } else {
                        //find a class which is free to remap to
                        size_t x = 0;
                        for (; x < counts.size() && counts[x]; x++) {}
                        ecs[current_ec] = x; //remap
                        //swap counts
                        counts[x]++;
                        counts[current_ec]--; 
                        current[i] = x;
                    }
                } else {
                    counts[remapped_ec]++;
                    counts[current_ec]--;
                    current[i] = remapped_ec;
                }
            }
        }
        //we can patch up the returned table at the end by remapping
        //values as we did at the start
        return current;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you want a _minimal perfect hash function_.  There is one relevant paper that discusses this kind of hash function: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.06416.pdf

Comment: I think a minimal perfect hash function is in the realm of what I'm after, however of what I've seen the algorithms which generate a minimal perfect hash don't map to a range of [0,M). I think gperf does some work to create an mph that functions this way, if I could make sense of that, but not have it be a command line tool. I'm operating at compile time here I guess I should mention.

Comment: Couldn't remember what minimal perfect hash meant, had to double check. It does seem to be what I'm after. Thing is I'm constructing this at compile time. It's a bit difficult to make sense of the several algorithms mentioned in that paper. Although I've already constructed a table for 8 bit values. I might need someone to explain what exactly is going on for one of these algorithms.

Comment: Your code might, but your description does not describe what form your equivalence classes take.  Is the algorithm free to invent the equivalence classes?  Are they always intervals?  Are they an input to the algorithm?

Comment: The actual problem is to classify characters in a regular expression. So the equivalence classes are the sets of characters which behave the same as part of a regex. This is why I don't particularly care the output integers for a given set of integers, in the end it's all the same. In the function I gave as an example the first argument is the table, the second argument is a new set of integers to add (assuming it was an equivalence class, it creates new equivalence classes as it goes). I freely remap the classes around.
The 32 bit input space is because utf8.

Comment: In short, whatever form the function generator takes it may remap equivalence classes as it goes, that's fine, I've done that for the smallest table. The sets aren't always intervals, they could very much be a mess. Technically one solution I suppose is to work out all the intervals in order, do a series of comparisons for each interval, return the interval #, and then compare those yet again if the value is equivalent to a smaller interval return that # instead. I don't imagine that being particularly nice. This is why I'm leaning towards whatever bithackery someone may enlighten me with.